# Angular frontend is loading up with no errors but none of the matticons or other angular/material are showing up on the page correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

here are my header component ts, css and html files.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrl: './header.component.css',
})
export class HeaderComponent {

}
```

html

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
<mat-toolbar-row>
    <span>Youtube Growth</span>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <button mat-icon-button class="example-icon favorite-icon" aria-label="Example icon- 
      button with heart icon">
  <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
</button>
<button mat-icon-button class="example-icon" aria-label="Example icon-button with share 
icon">
  <mat-icon>share</mat-icon>
</button>
```

The css is a simple flex operation and is working fine and isnt relevant to the question.
Now for my app.module components that are relevant.
html.

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UploadVideoComponent } from './upload-video/upload-video.component';
import { NgxFileDropModule } from 'ngx-file-drop';
import {HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import {MatToolbar, MatToolbarRow} from "@angular/material/toolbar";
import {MatIcon} from "@angular/material/icon";
import { SaveVideoDetailsComponent } from './save-video-details/save-video- 
details.component';
import {FlexLayoutModule, FlexModule} from "@angular/flex-layout";
import {MatFormField} from "@angular/material/form-field";
import {MatOption, MatSelect, MatLabel} from "@angular/material/select";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UploadVideoComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    SaveVideoDetailsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgxFileDropModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatToolbar,
    MatIcon,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    MatFormField,
    MatSelect,
    MatOption,
    MatLabel,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FlexModule,
    MatToolbarRow
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as im brand new to angular. If any more details are necessary pls let me know. As there are NO Error messages I didnt include that. the webpage is dispaying the text in the html file but is missing the colors and icons. Also, although im not sure if this is an intellij thing or not, im getting a highlight on maticon and other html elements that say - Unknown html tag mat-toolbar-row etc.

Comment: Can you try to add `MatIconModule` in the imports ? Also, track the "request" tab in the dev tools, you should the the `GET` requests corresponding to the images

Comment: `MatToolbarModule` is also not in the `imports` array

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are some missing modules in AppModule:

```
  imports: [
    MatToolbarModule, 
    MatIconModule,
    .....
```

And don't forgot to import icons fonts in your index.html :

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: ok will try, thanks. But shouldnt relevant fonts etc already be included in the imported Library?

Comment: ive imported the icons and included the correct import module statements, but still nothing sadly.

Comment: Can you share stackblitz?